# ObjectListView flickering when row hovered

Tags: c#, objectlistview

My .NET Winforms ObjectListView is flickering when I hover the rows (not the empty space in the list).

I have read that this can happen when using VirtualMode, but I am not.

I only have 2 items in my list and I am not refreshing it.

I have set `DoubleBuffered = true` for my parent window.

Any suggestions on how to stop the flickering, or why it is occurring?

Comment: This was a long time ago but do you remember if you ever worked this out? I am having the same issue?

Comment: No unfortunately I can't remember ever fixing it. I think I had to bail on that approach and try something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

before running the form.

Comment: Did this - didn't help

Comment: What version do you use?

Answer (score -1):

Set these properties for your listview control:

```
Activation = System.Windows.Forms.ItemActivation.Standard;
HotTracking = false;
HoverSelection = false;
```

Comment: I don't see 'HotTracking' or 'HoverSelection' properties in the ObjectListView class.. looks like they're explicitly hidden in the PreFilterProperties override?